# How to find when an SSL certificate was bounded to a site in IIS?

Tags: ssl, iis, iis-8.5

In IIS, we created a self-signed SSL certificate few days back. We wanted to see the date/timestamp when that certificate was bounded with the website. How can we do that?

We are using Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.

Thanks.

Comment: Certificate mapping is done via HTTP API, which I don't think gives you that time stamp. IIS might show you when the HTTPS site binding was created, only if you enabled auditing, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/19/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing/

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of audit log to see when certificates were bound to iis?

Comment: @Joe yes, something that tells me date and time when certificate was bounded to a website in IIS, not when the certificate was created.